# What does "all that" mean in this context?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, phrases

Source: [6 Minute English - What’s in a name?](http://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/features/6-minute-english/ep-180201)

> That's what we're talking about in this 6 Minute English. A husband taking a wife's name after marriage. **All that**, six related words and our quiz question.

What does "all that" mean in this context? I guess it could mean "and".

Comment: “All that and” could be replaced with “Everything mentioned up to this point and”.

Answer (score 1):

I think it simply refers to what was said previously. I. e., one could expand it to say, "So, we are going to discuss all that (the topic of husband taking a wife's name), we'll introduce six new words related to the topic, and we'll have a quiz question."

Answer (score 0):

It could be a commentary on the social issues involved with a husband taking a wife's name after marriage, and the incongruity of fitting 'all that' into a 6 minute English lesson.